# How we can get GPS location within a mobile app written in React Native

Tags: react-native, gps, mobile-application

I have written a mobile app in React Native. I need to have user GPS location in some time steps. Does any one know what is the best library and method to get GPS location within a mobile app written in React Native? **( for both IOS and android )**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation)

Install it first:

> npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save
>
> react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation

Then, to request access to location, you need to add the following line to your app's AndroidManifest.xml

Then use it on your app:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```